# Group By using Mysql 5.7 and Ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have Sql Query like this

```
SELECT sig_name, sig_class_id, label,  sig_priority, status, COUNT(*) as c FROM acid_event GROUP BY sig_name
```

and the code like this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if($row['status']==0 && $row['label']=='High'){
        echo $row['c']." ".$row['sig_name']." ".$row['label']."<br>"; //Here is your count
        $content = "ALARM\n ". $row['sig_name'] . "\nTotal : ". $row['c']. "\nLabel : " .$row['label'];
        sendMessage($chatid, $content, $token);
        $upstatus = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE acid_event SET status = '1' WHERE sig_class_id = '$row[sig_class_id]' AND sig_priority = '$row[sig_priority]'");
    }
    }
```

But there is no error and no output (while code not execute). Is there wrong with my code?
I want make output like "SIG NAME : XXXX and TOTAL : xxx"

**I was disabled `only_full_group_by`**

Update : if I execute that sql by phpmyadmin the output is 
[image]

Comment: you where disabled by a query that GROUPed by `sig_name`, and had `sig_class_id`, `label` and `sig_priority` in the result set, but not in the `GROUP BY`. Changing the sql_mode only hides the problem that you may be getting incorrect results.

Comment: Maybe show us some sample input data and the output you expect.  Your current `GROUP BY` query is basically invalid, because you are selecting non aggregate columns.

Comment: @danblack I run that query in phpmyadmin theres no error and the output is appear (look update question)

Comment: If there was another `DdoS UDP` that had a sig_class_id other than 3, or a label other than "High", or a sig_prioirty other than 2, or a status other than 1, what would you expect it display for that row?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated question, I just want to group that input by sig_name. Count if there are multiple sig_name

Comment: If you just want the `sig_name` and counts, then use `SELECT sig_name, COUNT(*) AS total FROM acid_event GROUP BY sig_name`.  This should work.

Comment: aside: phpmyadmin does some sneaking things, like in this case changing the `sql_mode`, meaning, like you've found out, a query in the browser isn't the same as a query in code. Always recheck in a real mysql cli a query that's displaying inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @danblack If there is row with status = 0 and label = high, it will execute sendMessage() with content = sig_name, label, total. That total depends on sig_name. Sorry if I can't explain clearfully

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but I need label and c(total) to use for sendMessage(content)

Comment: OK...edit your question and throw away everything _except_ for the query, the sample input, and the expected output.  We _don't_ need to see your PHP code.

Comment: Ah, so you may as well have `WHERE status=0 AND label="High"` in your query and leave the `if` statement in your PHP out. This still leaves `sig_priority` as an ungrouped field, maybe `MAX(sig_priority)`  is the right choice for the result field for this.

Comment: @danblack oh yes thats work for my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as mention in comment by @danblack

Answer (score 0):

try using `max()` on columns with multiple possible results instead or aggregate functions
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: note, try to provide links to the quoted MySQL major version (in the title). Not much difference on this page, but for other answers there can be.

Answer (score 0):

does query runs ok? if does try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    if($row['status']==0 && $row['label']=='High')
    {
        echo $row['c']." ".$row['sig_name']." ".$row['label']."<br>";
        $content = "ALARM\n ". $row['sig_name'] . "\nTotal : ". $row['c']. "\nLabel : " .$row['label'];
        sendMessage($chatid, $content, $token);
        $upstatus = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE acid_event SET status = '1' WHERE sig_class_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($row['sig_class_id']) . "' AND sig_priority = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($row['sig_priority']) . "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought query doesn't work, my code doesn't execute the while or sendMessage function